# How to Remove Authenticated Proxy from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: internet, proxy

I used to access my internet from an authenticated proxy ethernet. Hence I had created a apt.conf file under etc/apt. But now I want to access my internet without the proxy(a proxy free internet) so I want to remove this file. When I try to delete or edit this file, it says access is denied.

Please suggest what should i do to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you use `sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf` on a terminal to delete your file?

Comment: Both this comment (^) and the answer below will work.

Comment: Thanks Jobin. I was able to delete the file by that command. Silly of me that I didnt try that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this GUI method works...

Open *Dash* by hitting the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (aka   <kbd>[image: WindowsKey]</kbd>   key in Windows keyboard)

Type *system settings* and click the icon for system settings in the Dash menu
[image: 1]

In the **System Settings** window click on *Network*
[image: 2]

Now in the **Network** window select *Network Proxy* and set **Method** to *None*, click *Apply system wide* and supply the password to apply the changes to the system.
[image: 3]